# is it possible to define a automatically changing variable?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, countdown

I want to run two function. first one is normally run all the time but every 10 minutes second function should run. So I planed to define a timer global variable. But i don't know whether it is possible or not if it is possible please guide me in a correct way if its not possible give alternative solution
Here is what I've done so far

```
def func1():
    """something goes here"""

def func2():
    """something goes here"""

timer = """count down of 10 minutes"""

if timer<"""10 minutes""":
    func1()
else:
    func2()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend time.sleep

```
import time
func2()
time.sleep(600)
```

The time library can be useful for a lot of things :)

-- Dylan

Answer (score 0):

you can use sleep()

```
import time
func2()
time.sleep(600)
func1()
```